# Remove input masks on Successful Submit only

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, validation, maskedinput

I am currently using this script to remove my masks on submit:

```
$(".active_validator").submit(function() {
    $('.money_mask').unmask();
    $('.num_mask_thou').unmask();
    $('.zipcode').unmask();
    $('.only_numbers').unmask();
});
```

What I am realizing is that if an error occurs during submit, lets say a user did not fill out a field, it still removes the masks.

How do I only make it remove the masks on a 'successful' submit verses any submit?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out Answer:

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
            $('.money_mask').unmask();
            $('.num_mask_thou').unmask();
            $('.zipcode').unmask();
                form.submit();
            }
```